# "No point in" vs. "no point of" vs. "no point to"

Tags: word-choice, differences, prepositions, collocation

*Point in*, *point of*, *point to*. (*Point* in the sense of "purpose".) What are the differences among these — in meaning? in usage (each is used in certain constructions or with certain collocates, say)? in dialect? in register? etc.

Some examples (though I'm asking more generally than just about these examples):

> (1a) There's no point in going.
>   (1b) There's no point of going.
>   (1c) There's no point to going.
>
> (2a) Is there a point in his action?
>   (2b) Is there a point of his action?
>   (2c) Is there a point to his action?
>
> (3a) What's the point in that sculpture's being there?
>   (3b) What's the point of that sculpture's being there?
>   (3c) What's the point to that sculpture's being there?

Comment: Answer: it all depends. In your examples, 1b is awkward if not ungrammatical; 2b likewise, and 2c conveys the meaning best while 2a is ambiguous (could refer to *point in time*); any of the third group could be used, though I would favor 3b.

Comment: It's also sometimes used with no preposition at all; I think your (1a-c) examples wouldn't require a preposition if your gerund phrase were a bit longer, e.g. ["There's no point arguing about it."](https://www.google.com/search?q="there's+no+point+arguing+about+it")

Comment: @ruakh: Far more people keep the preposition with *"There's no point in arguing"* than drop it. Checking Google Books, it's still 2:1 in favour of keeping it with *"There's no point in arguing about it"*. But we know it's "wrong", which is why we don't do this so often in shorter constructions, where it's more noticeable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: To be clear: I wasn't saying that "There's no point arguing about it" is *better* or *more common* than "There's no point in arguing about it." I was merely pointing out that the former is in use. (But I don't know about your "'wrong'"-ness explanation for why it's more common with longer phrases. I can think of other explanations that seem more plausible to me; and I have no idea how to test any of them.)

Comment: @ruakh: I'm intrigued. The gerund *arguing* is still a noun, even if you extend it into a noun phrase such as *arguing endlessly about this minor detail*. How could anything like that affect the "grammaticality" of not using a preposition?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Firstly -- gerunds aren't exactly nouns; they're verb forms that share nounish behaviors, but they can be modified by adverbs (as you've just shown: "arguing endlessly" = "endless arguing"), and they can take direct objects ("arguing a point" = "the arguing of a point"). Secondly -- length can affect grammaticality; \*"he gave to the congregation one" is not grammatical (it has to be "he gave one to the congregation" or "he gave the congregation one"), but "he gave to the congregation not just one, not just two, but almost twenty!" is fine. Thirdly -- *[continued]*

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *[continued]* Thirdly -- *that*-clauses, though like gerunds they sometimes behave nounishly ("That he came was not a surprise" = "His arrival/coming was not a surprise"), are not introduced by prepositions ("I was surprised that he came" = "I was surprised by his arrival/coming" ≠ \*"I was surprised by that he arrived"). Gerunds frequently *are* introduced by prepositions, so they're nounier than *that*-clauses in this respect, but it doesn't seem strange to me that longer gerund-phrases could behave more *that*-clause-like in some cases.

Comment: The preposition depends on the purpose/disposition of the subject. Your question is akin to asking the difference between, - There are no roads to Rome.
- There are no roads in Rome.
- There are no roads for Rome. ~ - What is the purpose in asking that question?
- What is the purpose to be able to live eternally?
- What is the purpose for the existence of human kind?

Comment: @ruakh: Hmm. I don't see quibbling about how "nounish" gerunds are makes any difference. And in the case of *"to give"*, the point is we don't need the preposition in simple forms like *"He gave me it"*, but if either or both of the objects (me/it) turn out to be long phrases, we're more likely to include one - and recast as *"He gave a somewhat longer sequence of words **to** me"*. Longer structure seem to me *more* likely to require prepositions, as the interrelationships between components get swallowed up by the sheer weight of words.

Comment: It is quite common for prepositions to get dropped as language evolves. *It depends where you live* is more common than *It depends on where you live.* I suspect that *There's no point arguing* will soon become more common, too. There's no point in arguing about it.

Comment: I suspect the loss of the preposition could be influenced by seemingly parallel constructions using ‘dummy-its’, as in, “It’s no use arguing about it”. If ‘there’ is seen as an empty dummy-subject like ‘it’, the preposition would easily be lost, and the phrase would ultimately be, “Arguing about it is no point” on some level or other.

Answer (score 12):

There's no "rule" here - just established idiomatic norms.

> 1a - **There's no point in going.** *(most common)*
>    1b - There's no point of going. *(non-standard)*
>    1c - There's no point to going. *(sometimes acceptable)*
>
> 2a - Is there a point in his action? *(often acceptable)*
>    2b - Is there a point of his action? *(non-standard)*
>    2c - **Is there a point to his action?** *(most common)*
>
> 3a - What's the point in that sculpture's being there? *(often acceptable)*
>    3b - **What's the point of that sculpture's being there?** *(most common)*
>    3c - What's the point to that sculpture's being there? *(sometimes acceptable)*

(Most speakers would drop the *apostrophe+s* on the last three.)

Comment: Nice sets! I agree with FumbleFingers' judgements. What I notice is the different predicates of the prepositions in each of your groups. in + gerund (N over V)
to + noun (just N)
of + gerundive phrase? (NP over VP-with-subject: "that sculpture is there") This might explain part of the differences.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It would be nteresting to compare with what happens when substituting `reason` for `point`.

Comment: @schremmer: If you could come up with 3 prepositions capable of being used after ***reason***, and 3 sets of example usages featuring each different preposition (wherein every preposition appears once only, as the *most common* form within the "triplet"), I would surely upvote it with bells on! I suspect that may not be possible, though. Or if you think that one's too easy, try figuring out the other 8 examples to go with *There is **method in** my madness!*